# Why do i get this Python indentation error?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a indentation error in Python and i dont know why and how to resolve it.

I looked for special characters that i might have missed, but none found;

Why do i get this error ?

```
user = {'_id':username}

users.find_one(user)
```

[image]

IN CONCLUSSION : NEVER MIX TABS WITH SPACES!

Comment: you probably have an inconsistency btw tabs and multiple spaces.

Comment: Did you change editors half way through? Or copy code from somewhere? Check you editor's setting for what the tab button does, it might be set to put 4 spaces instead of a tab.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian: Don't use tabs. Use spaces. Quote from PEP 8: "For new projects, spaces-only are *strongly recommended* over tabs."

Comment: the guys from 10gen should have sayd these things; i did not know that using spaces and tabs is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason for this type of error is **mixing tabs and spaces**.

To fix it try converting all tabs to spaces in your file.

From [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

> **Tabs or Spaces?**
>
> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most editors have features that make this easy to do.

Comment: i was following a quiz, and they used spaces, i used tabs; now, everythign is ok

Answer (score 3):

you should check for tab and space mixes:

```
python -tt blog.py
```

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian it doesn't depends on platform.

Comment: on my win 7 it doesnt run, i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

Tabs mixed with spaces is a common cause of this issue. Try reformatting your document which should help fix the issue.